# Ampak AP6212 wifi driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, bluetooth

I have a mini-pc running Linux with the Ampak AP6212 chipset. The bluetooth and the WiFi modules are not working under Ubuntu 16.04. According to [this site](http://linux-sunxi.org/Wifi#Ampak_Devices) I need to install `brcmfmac`. Is this correct? If so, from which repository can I do so?

```
$ dmesg | grep brcm; ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
AcpiGlobalVariable-c020489e-6db2-4ef2-9aa5-ca06fc11d36a
AuthVarKeyDatabase-aaf32c78-947b-439a-a180-2e144ec37792
BackupPlatformLang-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
Boot0000-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Boot0001-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Boot0002-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Boot0004-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Boot2001-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Boot2002-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Boot2003-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
BootCurrent-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
BootOrder-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
BootType-a04a27f4-df00-4d42-b552-39511302113d
BugCheckCode-ba57e015-65b3-4c3c-b274-659192f699e3
BugCheckParameter1-ba57e015-65b3-4c3c-b274-659192f699e3
BugCheckProgress-ba57e015-65b3-4c3c-b274-659192f699e3
certdb-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
ColdQ2SEnableVariable-cccd8c8e-8915-4d12-bb76-0d49b4fc0dcd
ConIn-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
ConInCandidateDev-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
ConInDev-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
ConO ut-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
ConOutCandidateDev-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
ConOutDev-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
CurrentPolicy-77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b
Custom-a04a27f4-df00-4d42-b552-39511302113d
CustomSecurity-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
db-d719b2cb-3d3a-4596-a3bc-dad00e67656f
dbDefault-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
dbx-d719b2cb-3d3a-4596-a3bc-dad00e67656f
dbxDefault-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
ErrOutDev-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
IrsiInfo-5bce4c83-6a97-444b-63b4-672c014742ff
KEK-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
KEKDefault-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Lang-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
LangCodes-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
LastBootOSVariable-936d3077-9722-41a8-88ae-91a7b7594a3c
MemoryConfig-10ba6bbe-a97e-41c3-9a07-607ad9bd60e5
MemoryOverwriteRequestControl-e20939be-32d4-41be-a150-897f85d49829
MsdmAddress-fd21bf2b-f5d1-46c5-aee3-c60158339239
MTC-eb704011-1402-11d3-8e77-00a0c969723b
OfflineUniqueIDEKPubCRC-eaec226f-c9a3-477a-a826-ddc716cdc0e3
OfflineUniqueIDEKPub-eaec226f-c9a3-477a-a826-ddc716cdc0e3
OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
OsIndicationsSupported-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
PhysicalBootOrder-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
PK-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
PKDefault-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
PlatformCpuInfo-10ba6bbe-a97e-41c3-9a07-607ad9bd60e5
PlatformInfo-10ba6bbe-a97e-41c3-9a07-607ad9bd60e5
PlatformLang-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
PlatformLangCodes-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Regparm-49e3577e-71fb-46cc-a4a3-21084b7bd99f
RestoreFactoryDefault-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
SecureBootEnforce-59d1c24f-50f1-401a-b101-f33e0daed443
Setup-a04a27f4-df00-4d42-b552-39511302113d
SetupMode-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
SignatureSupport-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
SmmEmmcCardDataVariable-3503b13d-2bd7-43ca-ba63-a1dfaa68da46
Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
TrEEPhysicalPresence-f24643c2-c622-494e-8a0d-4632579c2d5b
TrEEPhysicalPresenceFlags-f24643c2-c622-494e-8a0d-4632579c2d5b
VendorKeys-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c

$ cat /etc/lsb-release; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
```

Link to [`wireless-info` results](http://txt.do/do5aI).

Updated output of `dmesg | grep brcm`:

```
[    6.587443] brcmf_sdio_drivestrengthinit: No SDIO Drive strength init done for chip 43430 rev 0 pmurev 24
[    6.590452] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    7.706117] brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[    8.710637] brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[    9.714375] brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50

$ dmesg | grep brcm
[    6.590452] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[ 1503.630948] Modules linked in: asix usbnet mii input_leds joydev     hid_microsoft hid_generic gpio_keys axp20x_pek snd_soc_sst_baytrail_pcm axp288_adc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel usbhid kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crc32_pclmul aesni_intel brcmfmac aes_i586 xts lrw gf128mul ablk_helper brcmutil cryptd cfg80211 bmc150_accel_spi bmc150_accel_i2c bmc150_accel_core jsa1212 kxcjk_1013 industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf snd_intel_sst_acpi industrialio snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_rt5640 goodix snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi mei_txe mei lpc_ich snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer 8250_fintek
[ 1503.730939] Modules linked in: asix usbnet mii input_leds joydev hid_microsoft hid_generic gpio_keys axp20x_pek snd_soc_sst_baytrail_pcm axp288_adc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel usbhid kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crc32_pclmul aesni_intel brcmfmac aes_i586 xts lrw gf128mul ablk_helper brcmutil cryptd cfg80211 bmc150_accel_spi bmc150_accel_i2c bmc150_accel_core jsa1212 kxcjk_1013 industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf snd_intel_sst_acpi industrialio snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_rt5640 goodix snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi mei_txe mei lpc_ich snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer 8250_fintek
[ 1503.963036] Modules linked in: asix usbnet mii input_leds joydev hid_microsoft hid_generic gpio_keys axp20x_pek snd_soc_sst_baytrail_pcm axp288_adc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel usbhid kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crc32_pclmul aesni_intel brcmfmac aes_i586 xts lrw gf128mul ablk_helper brcmutil cryptd cfg80211 bmc150_accel_spi bmc150_accel_i2c bmc150_accel_core jsa1212 kxcjk_1013 industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf snd_intel_sst_acpi industrialio snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_rt5640 goodix snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi mei_txe mei lpc_ich snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer 8250_fintek
[11622.144368] usbcore: deregistering interface driver brcmfmac
[11642.563260] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `dmesg | grep brcm; ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Added to the question.

Comment: You had a typo at the beginning of the command it was dmesg not mesg

Comment: @Jeremy31 same output.

Comment: Post results for `cat /etc/lsb-release; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31 posted.

Comment: @Curvature - Please also include, as requested, the results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` (it's a different command), Same for the first request: `ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars` is another command.

Comment: @MichaelBay the commands `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` and `dmesg | grep brcm` yield no output.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and post a link to your wireless script results.  The module brcmfmac is part of the 16.04 kernel

Comment: @Jeremy31 posted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of a mess.  Edit your /etc/rc.local file to remove
`echo "148F 7601" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id` as that USB device is not supported by ath9k_htc, it is a Mediatek device.

Delete all contents of /etc/modules as you don't need to force load ath9k and ath9k_htc.

Uninstall ndiswrapper and get rid of its configuration file.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf
```

Remove the Broadcom proprietary module.

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Let's make sure its blacklist file is gone.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Update the module alias list.

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot and look at `dmesg | grep brcm` to see if the issue is gone.

Comment: edited the question to include the updated output of the command.

Comment: Please post new results for the wireless script

Comment: http://txt.do/do5xz

Comment: I am a bit stumped as these SDIO cards usually look for a firmware file that isn't part of linux-firmware and is usually found in  /sys/firmware/efi/efivars and renamed to this file, but your computer doesn't even show the correct file in efivars.  What does `ls /sys/bus/platform/drivers/sdhci-acpi` show

Comment: I get the following output: `80860F14:00
80860F14:02
bind
INT33BB:00
module
uevent
unbind`

Comment: Try `echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/sdhci-acpi/INT33BB\:00/power/control ` Then `sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac && sleep 20 && sudo modprobe brcmfmac`  Then check results for `dmesg | grep brcmfmac`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62678/discussion-between-jeremy31-and-curvature).